# Unsticky a cout modifier?

Tags: c++, cout

```
  cout << hex << 11 << endl;
  cout << 12 << endl;
```

will print :

a

b

If I cout 13, it will be printed as 'c'. How do I remove the hex modifier from now on so it would just print 13?
This is probably simple but I tried looking for the answer elsewhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write in your code:

```
cout << dec << 13
```

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look at the Boost iostream [state saver](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/io/doc/ios_state.html) library. This makes it fairly easy to save a state, set a new state, then restore the original (saved) state.

Comment: This works in the general case, but seems overkill for just a change in base. +1 in any case.

Comment: @BillyONeal:If you really know that you're only going to change one thing, then it probably is overkill. Though it may have been incorrect, my assumption was that the base was an example, not necessarily the only attribute that would ever be involved.

Comment: Which is why I gave you +1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << dec
```

Also look [here](http://cplus.about.com/od/learning1/ss/clessontwo_4.htm)

Answer (score 1):

```
using namespace std;
cout<<hex<<11<<endl;
cout<<dec<<12<<endl;
cout<<13<<endl;
```